# can't add a color border to button

Tags: c#, xaml, user-interface

I'm trying to create a white border for the buttons in xaml but the border doesn't show

XAML

```
<Window x:Class="useless trash here that nobody cares">

    <Window.Resources>
        <Style TargetType="Button">
            <Setter Property="Width" Value="200"/>
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="#FF151515"/>
            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="White"/>
            <Setter Property="Height" Value="50"/>
            <Setter Property="FontFamily" Value="Arial"/>
            <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Left"/>
            <Setter Property="Width" Value="500"/>


            <Setter Property="Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="Button">
                        <Border Background="{TemplateBinding Background}">
                            <ContentPresenter HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
                        </Border>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
            <Style.Triggers>
                <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                    <Setter Property="Background" Value="#FF2E2E2E"/>
                </Trigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </Window.Resources>
    <Grid>
        <ScrollViewer HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" >
            <Button Content="Button" BorderBrush="#FFDC3B3B"/>
        </ScrollViewer>

        <TextBox x:Name="LaunchP" FontFamily="Cascadia Mono SemiBold" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" TextChanged="updateLaunchParams" Height="18" Width="500" />

    </Grid>
</Window>
```

The button properties also doesn't work for setting the **BorderBrush** or the **BorderThickness**

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/wpf/controls/button-styles-and-templates?view=netframeworkdesktop-4.8

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed it by adding the properties to the `<template>` tag